# How to schedule tasks with node-schedule in a for loop?

Tags: node.js, express

I have a problem where I have to schedule some tasks at different times in a day, for that one time scheduling I am using a cron to get all the data and schedule it accordingly but when i schedule the job in a FOR loop. each job gets executed multiple times. Here's my code

```
for(var i=0;i<_resultDataToPushLength;i++)
{
  var __date90=new Date(_DatesPlus90[i])
  var __date80=new Date(_DatesPlus80[i])
  var __rescheduleDate=new Date(_DatesToReschedule[i])
  var j = schedule.scheduleJob(scheduleId,[__date90,__date80,__rescheduleDate] ,     
function() {
  console.log(scheduleId)
})
```

}

This log prints multiple times...

Comment: why are you using for loop? There are already many types of scheduling options in the avalable node modules, like [node-cron](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron)

Comment: Actually I have to schedule the tasks everyday at 6:00am. So I get all the data from the database and start scheduling in a loop.

Comment: There is no need for `for` loops to do so, you can schedule your tasks with the module i've provided link to and make db calls as usual in that module.

Comment: Well but how can I cancel a Job as there are certain conditions where I have to cancel a job . In node-schedule we can easily do so by passing the job name to cancel() method

Comment: "Actually I have to schedule the tasks everyday at 6:00am." << so if you know you have to do it daily then do it, add condition before any operations in the scheduler

Comment: No if the user performs another action then I have to cancel the current schedule and crete another schedule for him and there are multiple users so there can be multiple crons running for every user. Now if I have to cancel one of them, There should be a reference to what I have to cancel and reschedule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, everything is working just fine its just that the dateTime in the arrays are past dates so the callback function gets executed once for every past dateTime.

Answer (score 0):

I think using async module will solve your issue.
heres the link https://github.com/caolan/async

try this code and see if it works

```
var async = require("async"); 
var arr = new Array();

for(var i=0;i<=datalength;i++){
    arr[i]=i;
}

async.forEach(arr,1,function(item,callback){
    var __date90=new Date(_DatesPlus90[i])
    ar __date80=new Date(_DatesPlus80[i])
    var __rescheduleDate=new Date(_DatesToReschedule[i])
    var j = schedule.scheduleJob(scheduleId,[__date90,__date80,__rescheduleDate] ,     
    function(){
        console.log(scheduleId);
        callback();
   });
});
```